# How to setup smsmanager.sendTextMessage pendingIntents in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, text

So this is my first app that I am developing in Kotlin and I decided to make a texting app for fun.  I was able to setup smsmanager.sendTextMessage to send a text out but I am having trouble setting up pendingIntents for it.  I found a lot of java tutorials which have been helpful for the most part but now I am stuck.

Here is my code thus far...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDSMS = 1
    var MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READCONTACTS = 1
    val messageText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message_text)
    val inputNumber = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.input_number)
    val inputMessage = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.input_message)
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.go_button)
    val inputManager:InputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READCONTACTS)
    }

    button.setOnClickListener{

        val enteredNumber = inputNumber.getText().toString()
        val enteredMessage = inputMessage.getText().toString()


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDSMS)
        }

        if(!isEmpty(enteredMessage) && !isEmpty(enteredNumber))
        {
            val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault() as SmsManager
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(enteredNumber, "12314370338", "$enteredMessage...Eat SHIT!", null, null)

            messageText.setText(enteredMessage)

            inputMessage.getText().clear()

            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                currentFocus?.windowToken,
                InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED
            )
        }else if(isEmpty(enteredNumber)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter a contact number.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else if(isEmpty(enteredMessage)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The message field can't be empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You broke something!  How did you get here?",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1.  Sanitize your code.  It's fully of hilarity.  2.  shouldn't $enteredMessage be outside of the quotes?

Comment: Well, I thought with Kotlin you don't need to concatenate strings, but this is my first one so I could be wrong.  Would you care to elaborate on the hilarities of the code?

Comment: the insults you sent to yourself.

Sorry i didn't realize it was kotlin so your syntax may be correct.